# Creating a project in visual studio

Tags: c#

Am try to create a project in VB2015 but the problem is when I select the type of the project c# and desktop application at last the ok button will not active pls I need a help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DzBQ.png)

Comment: Have you tried restarting visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

[image: open tools and features]

Then make sure the following is selected.

[image: what to select]

Comment: In my I can't get that option (get tool and features...)

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Am using VB2015

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of program you want to create. First, you have to choose your programming language (that is C#). Then you have to chose what kind of program you want to create - for example a WPF [Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiwaZ.png) or Console form application or maybe you want to make a class or interfaces and so on.

If you want to create a desktop application you have to choose one of these kind of projects: WPF and Windows Forms applications.

You select the create button then you must to choose your location in your computer and again you select the create button or else your VB2015 have been cracked.